# Rails 4: Edit and update Users atributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 4 application, where users only have to put there Email and Password to sign up and sign in. But the user's have more atributes like Image and Description, so I created an Edit and Update action, so Users can update their image and description... Here is my code:

Controller:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
@user = User.find(params[:id])
if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  redirect_to @user, :notice => 'Cadastro atualizado com sucesso!'
else
  render :edit
end
end
```

View: (users/edit)

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

Routes:

```
resources :users, :only => [:show, :edit, :update], :as => :user _No route matches [PUT] "/users/1/edit"_
```

But when I try to update I receive this message:  *No route matches [PUT] "/users/1/edit"* . Anyone know how to solve this? Thanks!

When I run rake routes I get:

```
 edit_user GET      /users/:id/edit(.:format)              users#edit
  user GET      /users/:id(.:format)                   users#show
       PATCH    /users/:id(.:format)                   users#update
       PUT      /users/:id(.:format)                   users#update
```

Answer (score 0):

We probably need to see the form to see the path that you're using, but it sounds like you're trying to PUT to `edit_user_path`, and you really need to PUT to `user_path`.  The edit path is GET only.

Also, not that you're asking about this.. but in your routes file, there should be no reason to need the `:as => :user` part of that.